# Fabric.js: the object on the canvas should be selected before a change is applied

Tags: fabricjs

I have a canvas with a text object on it. I change the 'textDecoration' property of the text object to underline. Nothing happens. I have to select the text object in order for the change to apply. I want the change to be applied immediately?

html:

```
<canvas id="customDesignCanvas"></canvas>
```

javascript:

```
var MyViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('customDesignCanvas');
  canvas.setDimensions({width: 513, height: 490});

   var text = new fabric.Text('test', { left: 100, top: 100 });
   text.setColor('red');

   canvas.add(text);

   text.set('textDecoration', 'underline');
}

var t = new MyViewModel();
```

I am just starting with Fabric.js. Any help will be appreciated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/138/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I should tell the canvas to re-render every time I make a change to some of its objects. After calling: `canvas.renderAll();` everything works as expected.